# How to pass the x.value of the last row in a lambda-x function applying to multiple columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, apply

I'm quite a newbie in Python and I'm facing a problem that I believe is in fact quite easy. yet, after ~48hours, I reaching out for help. I have a simple DataFrame, basically corresponding to "raw" concentration data (magnesium, sulfur etc...) that need some corrections.

```
d = {'Site': ['A',' A',' B',' B',' C',' C',' Seawater'], 'Mg':[52, 48.6, 50.7, 51.0, 27.2, 25.6, 52.2], 'S':[27, 25, 27, 26, 14, 15, 27.6],'K':[9, 9, 9.4, 9.3, 13, 13, 9], 'Ca': [10, 9, 10.3, 10, 20, 21, 10]}

df= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

```
        Site    Mg     S     K    Ca
0          A  52.0  27.0   9.0  10.0
1          A  48.6  25.0   9.0   9.0
2          B  50.7  27.0   9.4  10.3
3          B  51.0  26.0   9.3  10.0
4          C  27.2  14.0  13.0  20.0
5          C  25.6  15.0  13.0  21.0
6   Seawater  52.2  27.6   9.0  10.0
```

I aim to generate a new DataFrame of same size with corrected Mg, S, K and Ca values. Each value needs correction that depends on: the 'raw' value itself and the value of that same element in row 'Seawater', together with the Mg.value of that same row an the Mg.value in 'Seawater'.

This is what I wrote

```
New=df[['Mg','S','K','Ca']].apply(lambda x: (x - x.values[-1]) / (x['Mg'] + df['Mg'].values[-1]), axis = 1)
```

```
print(New)
```

As it is, it seems ok for picking the Mg values needed (the one of the same row and the one from last 'Seawater' row), it appears that x.values[-1] is not picking the last element of the column (value in 'Seawater'), but the last element of the row (which basically ends up to be Ca value).

Eventually, there will be much more columns in my dataframe and I liked the idea of passing this with a simple lambda x function. Can some good heart help ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```py
New = df[['Mg', 'S', 'K', 'Ca']].apply(lambda x: (x - df[x.index].values[-1]) / (x['Mg'] + df['Mg'].values[-1]), axis=1)
```

`x.values` only returns the values of the row you are currently applying to, so as you've observed already, `x.values[-1]` returns the value of the last column of that row, but not the last row of the column. To do so you need to get the name of the column you currently iterate over (`x.index`) and then you can access the 'seawater' value as you do for the 'Mg' column, using `df[x.index].values[-1]`.

Comment: Cool, glad to her! Would be nice if you could also "accept" my answer :)